# Jupiter testnet faucet link broken

Tags: smart-contract, faucet

The link on the `jupiter` [github](https://github.com/patractlabs/jupiter/) repo, the link for their faucet is broken. I was hoping to get some test DOT.

[image]

Anyone know which testnet could one use for WASM contract deploy and if they have a working link for their faucet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

patrastore.io is stopped, you can paste your address here or https://app.element.io/#/room/#PatractLabsDev:matrix.org

Comment: here is in on this thread? 5GNXzF9Qfx1cXVsNE3XVMY6CcqAhkXWXUZcqKPBHhDrTbsY2 (polka-extension)

Comment: done, you can visit https://app.element.io/#/room/#jupiter-faucet-room:matrix.org for faucet in the future.

Comment: thanks very much